# Aws lambda manages 2 status code for no errors event

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, http-status-codes

I'm studying AWS. At the moment I understood how to manage APIGateway to solve correct status code errors.

Now I would like to return 2 different "positive" status code (**200** and **202** depending by lambda logic..)

I know that mapping **200** without regex it will be the default one with no error, but I would like also to serve a **202** status code..

I've tried to raise an exception for **202** but if I implement the code that will match regex I can't give back also my response
and viceversa if I use "*mapping template*" I don't know how catch my data back.

I'm sure that is a logic mistake but I didn't understand well yet:

- How to trigger ApiGateway injecting also my Response?
- Is it the right way to use an exception to switch "positive" status
  code (cause like this I'll have a "wrong" exception event into the
  log...)?

(into comment the code/APIGateway cofiguration)

Comment: #PYTHON LAMBDA CODE

    if Condition:
        response = {'message': json.dumps('All done and you are into 202 status '), 'queue_id':myQueue }
        raise Exception( "202" , response ) 
    else:
        return {'message': json.dumps('All done. This is the END and you are into 200 status '), 'queue_id':myQueue }

#APIGATEWAY
    200 -> Lambda Error Regex "-"
    202 -> Lambda Error Regex ".*202*."

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code instead of pasting it inside of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem raise the response object into the exception, and using a key of this to trigger the Lambda Error Regex for the correct status code.
I don't know if is the right way but it works